# Windows explorer lookalike FTP client for Chromebooks

Tags: chrome, google-apps, ftp, chrome-os

Be aware: I am asking for software for Chrome OS.

I am looking for a program to access a NAS from my chromebook. I know i can do this in chrome by typing the ip and login information in the adress bar. However I would prefer a more simple program, like Windows explorer.

What it must do:
* remember my credentials
* work on ChromeOS
* Access ftp servers

By the way, it may also be a chrome extension, those do work on Chrome OS, whereas .exe files do not.